# Javascript - Fill area under a spline in an area chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to fill in the area between the red line(solar) and yellow bar(nuclear) in the graph below. I cannot for the life of me figure it out and am out of ideas.I'd like to fill it in red. Find my code below the image. 
I would also like to be able to have the red spline above nuclear without having to add the value of the grey, blue and yellow bar together and adding it to the solar value but could find no other way. 
 Thanks!

[image]

```
var TotalNonGreenPower = 200 + 300 + 500;
    var energyData = [
        { time: '12:00am', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 0 },
        { time: '2:00am', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 0 },
        { time: '4:00am', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 0 },
        { time: '6:00am', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 100 },
        { time: '8:00am', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 100 },
        { time: '10:00am', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 100 },
        { time: '12:00pm', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 200 },
        { time: '2:00pm', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 200 },
        { time: '4:00pm', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 100 },
        { time: '6:00pm', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 100 },
        { time: '8:00pm', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 0 },
        { time: '10:00pm', hydro: 200, solar: TotalNonGreenPower + 0 }
    ];

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Power Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: energyData.map(point => point.time),
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'MegaWatts'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                /*fillOpacity: 0.5*/
            },
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: 'Hydro',
                data: energyData.map(point => [point.time, point.hydro]),
                color: 'blue',
                type: 'area',
                index: 2
            },
            {
                name: 'Nuclear',
                data: energyData.map(point => [point.time, 300]),
                color: 'yellow',
                type: 'area',
                index: 1
            },
            {
                name: 'Gas',
                data: energyData.map(point => [point.time, 500]),
                color: 'gray',
                type: 'area',
                index: 3
            },
            {
                name: 'Solar',
                data: energyData.map(point => [point.time, point.solar]),
                color: 'red',
                type: 'spline',
                index: 0
            },
            {
                name: 'Curve',
                data: [
                    [energyData[0].time, 500],
                    ['10:00am', 1500],
                    ['8:00pm', 2000],
                    ['10:00pm', 500]
                ],
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                type: 'spline'
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: I found a solution to my second point as I am just updating the tooltip so this is fine now. I still can't figure out how to make the area under the spline red though.

Comment: Why don't you use the area series for that as well?

Comment: @magdalena I have tried using the area series but I cannot get it to only color in-between the yellow and the red line. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this with the area series?

Comment: You can resolve that by adding stacking only for the particular series. Example demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vcLsqrpu/